# How do I swap two items in an observableArray?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a button that moves an item one position left in an observableArray. I am doing it the following way. However, the drawback is that categories()[index] gets removed from the array, thus discarding whatever DOM manipulation (by jQuery validation in my case) on that node.

Is there a way to swap two items without using a temporary variable so as to preserve the DOM node?

```
    moveUp: function (category) {
        var categories = viewModel.categories;
        var length = categories().length;
        var index = categories.indexOf(category);
        var insertIndex = (index + length - 1) % length;

        categories.splice(index, 1);
        categories.splice(insertIndex, 0, category);
        $categories.trigger("create");
    }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's my version of `moveUp` that does the swap in one step:

```
moveUp: function(category) {
    var i = categories.indexOf(category);
    if (i >= 1) {
        var array = categories();
        categories.splice(i-1, 2, array[i], array[i-1]);
    }
}
```

That still doesn't solve the problem, though, because Knockout will still see the swap as a delete and add action. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/259) for Knockout to support moving items, though. *Update:* As of version 2.2.0, Knockout does recognize moved items and the `foreach` binding won't re-render them.

Comment: thanks a lot, here is the **moveDown** example http://stackoverflow.com/a/22348385/287084

Comment: Does not work in IE 11. The David Brown's approach did the trick though.

Answer (score 8):

I know this answer comes a bit late, but I thought it might be useful to others who want a more general swap solution. You can add a swap function to your observableArrays like so:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.swap = function(index1, index2) {
    this.valueWillMutate();

    var temp = this()[index1];
    this()[index1] = this()[index2];
    this()[index2] = temp;

    this.valueHasMutated();
}
```

You can then use this function to swap two elements in an array given their indices:

```
myArray.swap(index1, index2);
```

For a moveUp function, you could then do something like this:

```
moveUp: function(category) {
    var i = categories.indexOf(category);
    if (i > 0) {
        categories.swap(i, i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, even in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as I wanted jQuery drag & drop on my items.
My solution became to use knockoutjs templates to bind the beforeRemove and afterAdd events to the model. The Person Class/function is also a simple knockout view model.

In the below example I use .draggable(), but you could easily use validation. Add your own code for manipulating the observableArray and you should be good to go.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="template: {foreach:attendeesToShow, beforeRemove:hideAttendee, afterAdd:showAttendee}">
    <div class="person">
        <img src="person.jpg" alt="" />
        <div  data-bind="text: firstName" ></div>
        <div class="deleteimg" data-bind="click:$parent.removeAttendee" title="Remove"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var at = [new Person('First', 'Person', 'first@example.com'),
                    Person('Second', 'Person', 'second@example.com')
                ];
    self.attendees = ko.observableArray(at);

    self.removeAttendee = function (attendee) {
        self.attendees.remove(attendee);
    };

    this.showAttendee = function (elem) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
    $(elem).hide().show("slow").draggable();//Add jQuery functionality 
        }
    };
    this.hideAttendee = function (elem) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
            $(elem).hide(function () {
                $(elem).remove();
            });
        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Can elaborate? What I am attempting to do is to use buttons to allow the user to sort (might implement drag-and-drop later). How does handling beforeRemove, afterAdd preserve the DOM elements?
The DOM elements were generated by Knockout, but were changed by jQuery validation and I lose the changes by removing from then reinserting the item.

Comment: In my example I simply re-add the draggable, in your case validation, when the item is re-added to the DOM. In my case it does not need to preserve any state variables (they're all in the model) so it works for me. Shouldn't the validation be the same also?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [Michael Best](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287183/michael-best) for his version of moveup

my version of moveDown

```
moveDown: function(category) {
    var array = categories();
    var i = categories.indexOf(category);
    if (i < arr.length) {
        categories.splice(i, 2, array[i + 1], array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your version doesn't work correctly. Replacing "arr.length" with "array.length - 1" does the trick.