# Swapping elements in a KnockoutJS observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am wondering if there is a simple way to swap 2 elements in an observable array using KnockoutJS. I would think the function below would do the trick but I believe I am missing something here.

```
self.swap = function () {
    var tmp = self.dataArray()[0];
    self.dataArray()[0](self.dataArray()[1]);
    self.dataArray()[1](tmp);
}
```

Setting the tmp variable works as expected but when I try to set the array members themselves I receive an error "Object doesn't support property or function 0"

Comment: What exactly is `self.dataArray()`? In you example it may seem to be an array of observable arrays, but since you get the error, I don't think though. Do you just want to swap the first element of `self.dataArray` with the second one?

Comment: I answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10630319/1287183

Comment: Yes I just want to swap these two items as a simple example