# splice() not updating items order of array within knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Following a [prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258086/how-do-i-swap-two-items-in-an-observablearray) on how to update the order of an array. I followed the suggestion of Michael Best and used splice() to modify the ordering of my array on button click

```
self.moveup = function (itemIndex) {
    var i = self.itemList.indexOf(itemIndex); 
    if(i >= 1){
     var array = self.itemList();
        self.itemList.splice(i-1, 2, array[i], array[i-1]);
    }
```

Where I am having trouble is in incrementing the items in the array. [From reading the usage of Array Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) The first param indicates where the change should occur for moving up I would think that would be `i+1` , the value 2 indicates how many items in the array would change so no change there and then the range I thought would be the selected item array[i] and the end would be [i+1] as I am increasing the position.

```
self.itemList.splice(i+1, 2, array[i], array[i+1]);
```

In the attached fiddler you can see the values increase but the items do not actually change order they are only replicating when you hit the down button. I expected the result to be the same as when calling moveUp.

I'd appreciate any pointers on what I am missing here. http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/SCWmk/5/

-cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost there. [Here's how I did it.](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/jA9sS/)

When moving an item up, you need to swap it with the previous item. Thus, you need to replace the elements at indices `i-1` and `i` with `array[i]` and `array[i-1]`, respectively. Your `moveup` method does exactly that, so all is good.

Now, when moving an item down, you need to swap it with the *next* item. Thus, you replace the elements at indices `i` and `i+1` with `array[i+1]` and `array[i]`, respectively. Your code however changes the elements `i+1` and `i+2`, which is no good. Instead, you should be doing:

```
self.itemList.splice(i, 2, array[i+1], array[i]);
```

You start splicing at `i` (as you're removing the elements at `i` and `i+1`) and you replace them (insert at that index) with `array[i+1]` and `array[i]`.

On another note, your check for whether you can move the item down is incorrect. The only item you should not move down is the *last item*, i.e. the element at index `self.itemList().length-1`. Thus, the check should look like `if (i < array.length - 1) { ... }` (see the fiddle).