# Knockout move observableArray item down

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258086/how-do-i-swap-two-items-in-an-observablearray), i know how to move an item up:

```
moveUp: function(category) {
    var i = categories.indexOf(category);
    if (i >= 1) {
        var array = categories();
        categories.splice(i-1, 2, array[i], array[i-1]);
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent for moving the item down?

Comment: @Alexander: not working

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151354/splice-not-updating-items-order-of-array-within-knockout-js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this solution, i delete two items, from `index` position, and then again insert them (first - the next item, and the second - moving item):

```
moveDown = function(number) {
    var i = self.numbers().indexOf(number);
    if (i < self.numbers().length - 1) {
        var rawNumbers = self.numbers();
        self.numbers.splice(i, 2, rawNumbers[i + 1], rawNumbers[i]);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r9waX/)

Comment: works like a charm thnx a lot :) here is the **moveUp** example http://stackoverflow.com/a/10630319/287084