# Moving item down in ko.observableArray model binding issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

**Edit**

Apparently the logic is correct. I suspect the issue is with how I'm binding my View Model from the JSON response of our API. I've added more code to try and help diagnose the issue.

Am I binding the view model correctly?

**Original post**

I'm not asking how to move items around in an observableArray, I got my code to move items up and down inside an array from here: 
[How do I swap two items in an observableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258086/how-do-i-swap-two-items-in-an-observablearray)

Moving up by @Michael Best: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10630319/1888402

Moving down by @Moes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26726556/1888402

The problem I'm having is moving the item down. It moves up just fine, the issue seems to be with the logic.

**JSON Model**

```
{
  "Options": {
    "SelectedHeader": "Left Header",
    "AvailableHeader": "Right Header"
  },
  "Selected": [
    {
      "Order": 2,
      "ID": 1,
      "Label": "Duration"
    },
    {
      "Order": 11,
      "ID": 5,
      "Label": "Metres / Min"
    },
    {
      "Order": 23,
      "ID": 7,
      "Label": "Sprint Dis/Min"
    },
    {
      "Order": 9,
      "ID": 15,
      "Label": "Max Velocity"
    },
    {
      "Order": 6,
      "ID": 16,
      "Label": "Hi Intensity Running"
    }
  ],
  "Available": [
    {
      "ID": 123,
      "Label": "I'm Available"
    }
  ],
  "WebServiceMethodUrl": "../../../Services/SomeAsmxService.asmx/SaveStuff"
}
```

**View Model**

```
         function ViewModel(){
            var self = this;
            self.Options = model.Options
            self.Available = ko.observableArray(model.Available);
            self.Selected = ko.observableArray(model.Selected);
            self.WebServiceMethodUrl = model.WebServiceMethodUrl;
            self.addSelected = function(item){
                item.Order = self.Selected().length;
                self.Available.remove(item);
                self.Selected.push(item);
            };
            self.removeSelected = function(item){
                self.Available.push(item);
                self.Selected.remove(item);
            };
            self.moveUp = function(item) {
                var i = self.Selected.indexOf(item);
                if (i >= 1) {
                    var array = self.Selected();
                    self.Selected().splice(i-1, 2, array[i], array[i-1]); //Works fine
                    item.Order = i;
                }
            };
            self.moveDown = function(item) {
                var i = self.Selected.indexOf(item);
                if (i < self.Selected().length - 1) {
                    var array = self.Selected();
                    self.Selected().splice(i, 2, array[i + 1], array[i]);
                    item.Order = i;
                    self.Selected.valueHasMutated(); //Force rebind
                }
            };
            self.SaveIt = function(){
                postDataAsync(self.WebServiceMethodUrl, "{queryString: '"+ ko.toJSON(self) + "'}", "Could not save settings.", function (resp){});
            }
            self.sortedSelected = ko.computed(function(){
                return self.Selected().sort(function(left, right) { return left.Order == right.Order ? 0 : (left.Order < right.Order ? -1 : 1) });
            });
        }



        var vm = new ViewModel();

        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

**HTML & Bindings**

```
 <!-- ko if: sortedSelected().length -->
   <tbody data-bind="with:sortedSelected">
        <!-- ko foreach: Selected -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: (ID == 0) -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="order">

                        <p data-bind="click: moveUp, clickBubble: false"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></p>
                        <p data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></p>
                        <p data-bind="click: moveDown, clickBubble: false"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down move-down"></i></p>
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text:Label, attr: { id: ID }"></td>
                    <td><a class="remove" data-bind="click: removeSelected, clickBubble: false">Remove&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            <!-- /ko-->
        <!-- /ko-->
    </tbody>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

So if I was to call the moveDown function on item 5, it should then become item 6 and item 6 should become item 5. Not sure why this isn't working since it's just the logic being inverted.

**Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0g6wtpc/1/)

Comment: It's working for me. Also, no need to call `valueHasMutated` if you call splice on the observable array instead of the backing array. Also, this won't work correctly if used on the last index in the array. Change your check to `i < self.Selected().length - 1`.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to have to post more of my code.

Comment: You're not using Knockout's `splice`. Call it on the observableArray, not on the contents.

Comment: Please make a fiddle to show us what doesn't work.

Comment: Will do in about an hour or so.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, see updated answer for JSFiddle link. Notice how it's incredibly flaky, sometimes it will move down but won't do it again.

Comment: I noticed that you're calling applyBindings on your view model constructor instead of the view model instance you create the line before.

Comment: Once you fix that you'll notice all the context issues with your bindings. For instance you can't have a `foreach: Selected` inside of a `with: sortedSelected` because sortedSelected doesn't have a property called "Selected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `sortedSeleted` computed. Any time `Selected` is modified, the computed will be reevaluated because it has a dependency on `Selected`. When the computed is evaluated it sorts `Selected`. You may have not realized that`sort` modifies the array it is called on while also returning the array. This sorting by `Order` is what's making the `moveUp` and`moveDown` functions *appear* inconsistent.

You most likely want to sort a **copy** of `Selected`. As @RoyJ pointed out, you can use `slice` to get a shallow copy of an array.

Comment: And to sort without rearranging, you can slice the whole array: `self.Selected.slice().sort(...`

Comment: Thanks a lot @CrimsonChris, there were a bunch of issues but you helped me get to the bottom of them.